# Is Guru tattva and Shiva tattva the same?

Tags: shiva, guru, skanda-purana, kartikeya, iskcon

[From the lecture of HG Amogh Lila Prabhu](https://youtu.be/0n13r73pwP8)

3:08-3:13

HG says that :

> Guru tatva and Shiva tatva are the same.Like how the guru aids the student to reach Sri Krishna, so also Lord Shiva aids a devotee to reach Lord Krishna.

There is an account of how Skanda was asked by Lord Shiva to learn from Brahma. Brahma sends him back saying that Skanda answers/counters all that he is saying, and he wants to learn the meaning of Omkara at the beginning itself. Skanda asks Lord Shiva the same, and Shivji Himself smiles and says that he doesn’t.

So Skanda asks Lord Shiva to place him above Shivji’s shoulders, as Lord Shiva had asked Skanda to explain Omkara to him, and he could do that only him only if he was given the status of Guru.

So if in terms of tattva, Lord Shiva and guru are identical, then Skanda should have been on equal footing with Lord Shiva,**apparently contradicting what HG said.**

Answer (score 1):

There exists no difference between a guru and Shiva.

This is what god Shiva himself says in the Kāraṇa-āgama -

> ##### [Chapter 5](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n87/mode/2up) (pañcamaḥ paṭalaḥ): kriyāpādaḥ, Kāraṇāgama
>
> महादेव उवाच:
>
> > Bhagvān Shiva said -
>
> गुरुर्यतोऽहं देवेशि नावयोर्विद्यते भिदा । अभेदभावनां ज्ञात्वा तदाज्ञां
> परिपालयेत् ।।१५।।
>
> > 15. **O Devi! The reason is that I - Shiva, am only the preacher (guru) and there is no difference between the Preacher and Me, Shiva. While
> >     comprehending the idea of non-difference, the practitioner ought to carry
> >     out the command.**

##### So, YES.

- 'Shiva-tattva' and 'Guru-tattva' are one and the same.

Comment: Thank you,but on a side note:I’m not very aware of the Agamas.Is the above explanation valid for Vaishnav doctrine also?

Comment: Agamas are found in all sects. Vaihanavas have Pancaratras & Vaikhanasa. Gaudiya may not consider the Karanagma as authoritative. But, that doesn't diminish or take away the fact mentioned above. It is valid, and it actually corroborates the assertion made by Amogh Lila in the Video @Amethyst